# How to convert Nested JSONObject/JSONArray to flatJSON and produce multiple records

Tags: java

I wanted to convert a nested JSONObject to flatJSON and if JSONAArray is present it has to produce multiple records. So, I have written code using recursion which will convert nested JSON Object to flatJSON.

```
public class Test {


    public static Map<String,Object> flatJSON(Object obj,Map<String,Object> flatmap) {
        Iterator<?> keys = ((JSONObject) obj).keys();
        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) keys.next();
            if(((JSONObject) obj).get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {
                flatJSON(((JSONObject) obj).get(key), flatmap);
            }
            else if(((JSONObject) obj).get(key) instanceof JSONArray) {
                if(((JSONObject) obj).getJSONArray(key).optJSONObject(0)!=null) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = ((JSONObject) obj).getJSONArray(key).getJSONObject(0);
                    flatJSON(jsonObject, flatmap);
                }
                else {
                    flatmap.put(key, ((JSONObject) obj).get(key));
                }
            }
            else {
                flatmap.put(key, ((JSONObject) obj).get(key));
            }
        }
        return flatmap;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s="{\r\n" + 
                "  \"root\": {\r\n" + 
                "    \"data\": {\r\n" + 
                "      \"a\": \"1\",\r\n" + 
                "      \"b\": {\r\n" + 
                "        \"c\": \"2\"\r\n" + 
                "      },\r\n" + 
                "      \"test\": [\r\n" + 
                "        {\r\n" + 
                "          \"e\": \"3\"\r\n" + 
                "        },\r\n" + 
                "        {\r\n" + 
                "          \"f\": \"4\"\r\n" + 
                "        }\r\n" + 
                "      ],\r\n" + 
                "      \"test1\": [\r\n" + 
                "        {\r\n" + 
                "          \"g\": \"5\"\r\n" + 
                "        }\r\n" + 
                "      ],\r\n" + 
                "      \"test2\": [\r\n" + 
                "        1,\r\n" + 
                "        2,\r\n" + 
                "        3\r\n" + 
                "      ]\r\n" + 
                "    }\r\n" + 
                "  }\r\n" + 
                "}";
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println(flatJSON(new JSONObject(s), new HashMap<String, Object>()));
    }
```

But the above code works with only JSONObject, for JSONArray as a input how we can convert to flatJSON.Following are the example of input and expected output.

**EXAMPLE1:**

Input:

```
{
  "root": {
    "data": {
      "a": "1",
      "b": {
        "c": "2"
      },
      "test": [
        {
          "e": "3",
          "f": "5"
        },
        {
          "e": "4",
          "f": "6"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
  "a": "1",
  "c": "2",
  "e": "3",
  "f": "5"
}

{
  "a": "1",
  "c": "2",
  "e": "4",
  "f": "6"
}
```

**EXAMPLE2:**

Input:

```
{
  "root": {
    "data": {
      "a": "1",
      "b": {
        "c": "2"
      },
      "test": [
        {
          "e": [{"m":1},{"m":2}]
        },
        {
          "e": [{"m":3}]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
  "a": "1",
  "c": "2",
  "m": "1"
}

{
  "a": "1",
  "c": "2",
  "m": "2"
}
{
  "a": "1",
  "c": "2",
  "m": "3"
}
```

**EXAMPLE3:**

Input:

```
{
  "root": {
    "data": {
      "a": "1",
      "b": {
        "c": "2"
      },
      "test": [1,2,3]
    }
  }
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
  "a": "1",
  "c": "2",
  "test": "1"
}

{
  "a": "1",
  "c": "2",
  "test": "2"
}
{
  "a": "1",
  "c": "2",
  "test": "3"
}
```

How can I modify the above code for expected result.

Comment: Are you sure in your second example on the expected output that in all three cases there should be "m": "4"? Shouldn't it be "m": "1" / "m": "2" / "m": "3"?

Comment: sorry it is "m": "1" / "m": "2" / "m": "3" .I have updated the question now .Thank you